# How do I print all .pdf files names to an output file with command line?

Tags: windows, perl, command-line, printing

This seems easy in Linux, but I'm trying to print the names of `*.pdf` files within a directory and its subdirectories to an output file. I have Perl installed on my Windows machine.

What's a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Not much different than Linux.

```
dir *.pdf > fileyouwant.txt
```

If you only want the filenames, you can do that with

```
dir/b *.pdf > fileyouwant.txt
```

If you also want subdirs,

```
dir/s/b *.pdf > fileyouwant.txt
```

If you aren't in that directory to start with

```
dir/s/b C:\Path\*.pdf > fileyouwant.txt
```

Comment: This won't find files in subdirectories.

Comment: Does `dir` do the recursive search into sub-directories?

Comment: dir /s/b  does.  You'd have to cd into the target top directory first.

Comment: Nice. dir/s/b *.pdf >fileyouwant.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $dirname = shift or die "Usage: $0 dirname >outputfile";

File::Find::find( sub {
    print $File::Find::name, "\n" if $File::Find::name =~ /\.pdf\z/
}, $dirname );
```

Comment: This worked, but can I print the output to a file after it prompts me for the directory name?

Comment: @Jake: changed it to take the directory name as a command line parameter so output can be easily sent to a file

Answer (score 1):

[File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule) is often nicer to use than [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html).

```
use File::Find::Rule;

my $rule = File::Find::Rule->file()->name('*.pdf')->start('C:/Path/');
while (defined (my $pdf = $rule->match)) {
    print "$pdf\n";
}
```

or simply

```
use File::Find::Rule;

print "$_\n" for File::Find::Rule->file()->name('*.pdf')->in('C:/Path/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl, you should almost certainly be using the [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) core module.

Answer (score 0):

See the [File::Glob](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/prog/ch32_22.htm) module.

Specifically:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Glob ':glob'; # Override glob built-in.                          
print join("\n",glob("*.pdf"));
```

Comment: @ysth: my bad, but it might still be useful to somebody, so I'll leave it.