# Dos command geetting only file names recursively

Tags: batch-file, dos

I want to list all the names of files recursively from a folder. Checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515510/command-line-print-file-names-to-output-file) question, but it won't help me.

```
dir /b "*.xml"
```

will give me .xml files in current folder.

```
dir /b /s "*.xml"
```

This gives me full paths of files recursively. 
However, I need to get only the file names. How can this be achieved? Could this be done using FOR? Tried some things on FOR, but not working. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic is behind the handling of variables. See the bottom of the output of `for /?` for more explanation.

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /s /b *.xml') do @echo %~nxa
```